# Port Scanner - Can't Add All Opened Ports To A Variable (List)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, port, addition

My code won't display the opened_ports list containing all opened ports.
(I think it doesn't even add values to it. (Maybe overwriting?))
I already tried a few things but nothing will work.

BTW: Is there a way to sort the "Port x is closed."?

Output:

```
...
Port 97 is closed.
Port 100 is closed.

All opened ports within the selected range:
[]
```

Code:

```
import socket, threading, time
from queue import Queue

print_lock = threading.Lock()

target = input('Target:' + ' ')
workers = input('Workers:' + ' ')
first_port = input('First port:' + ' ')
last_port = input('Last port:' + ' ')

if first_port == 'min':
    first_port = 1
if last_port == 'max':
    last_port = 65536

print('\n' + 'Scanning...' + '\n')

def scan(port):
    soccer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket. SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        connection = soccer.connect((target, port))
        with print_lock:
            print('Port' + ' ' + str(port) + ' ' + 'is opened.')
            time.sleep(5)
            opened_ports = opened_ports + port
        connection.close()
    except:
        with print_lock:
            print('Port' + ' ' + str(port) + ' ' + 'is closed.')

def thread():
    while True:
        worker = queue.get()
        scan(worker)
        queue.task_done()

queue = Queue()
opened_ports = []

for x in range(int(workers)):
    threader = threading.Thread(target = thread)
    threader.daemon = True
    threader.start()

for worker in range(int(first_port), int(last_port)):
    queue.put(worker)

queue.join()

print('\n' + 'All opened ports within the selected range:' + '\n' + '\n' +
      str(opened_ports))
```

Comment: I would suggest changing the bare `except:` to something specific, or at least to `except Exception as exp:`, then `print(exp)`. It's possible something is raising an unexpected exception, but that fact is being hidden. Also you need to append new ports to the `opened_ports` list differently. One valid way is `opened_ports += [port]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `opened_ports = opened_ports + port` to `opened_ports.append(port)`